# How can I properly discern what base Error is used in Swift when throwing errors which extend it?

Tags: swift

I am looking how to know an error is of my type, `AppError`.

I basically have a class defined as `class AppError<ErrorType>: Error {`.

I then do

```
enum MyError {
    case noApp
    case noLabel
}
```

My throw is like `throw AppError(type: MyError.noApp)`

After my catch, I run a method where I am having trouble...

```
static func handle(error: Error) {
    print("App Error handled")
    print(error);
    let mine = error is AppError<Any>;
    // This is always false
    print(mine);
}
```

I tried `Any` and `AnyObject` as the Generic, but it's always false. The print of `error` always looks like `myapp.AppError<myapp.MyError>`

My intent is to know it's an `AppError` so I can call methods that are specific to it.

In practice I might have errors like `ConnectionError`, `CreateError`, etc. All of these would rely on `AppError`. I want my handler to know the passed error relies on `AppError`, which would have its own custom properties vs a generic error from a 3rd party library which wouldn't have those properties.

**Update**
Since it might not be possible to do this, I have tried the following:

```
class ErrorHandler {
    static func handle(error: Error) {
        print("App Error handled")
        print(error);
        switch error {
            // List all AppError<Types> here since <Any> won't work
            case is AppError<MyError>:
                self._handleAppError(error: error)
            default:
                print("Generic Error")
                print(error);
        }
    }

    private static func _handleAppError(error: AppError<Any>) {
        print("My error!");
        print(error);
        print(error.type);
    }
}
```

The issue there is that it complains `Cannot convert value of type 'Error' to expected argument type 'AppError<Any>` even though it's in a line that must be that type.

Comment: have you tried `let mine = error is AppError<MyError>`?

Comment: I don't get it, why is `AppError` generic? What's `ErrorType`?

Comment: `ErrorType`  is an `enum`.

@MilanNosáľ I didn't do `AppError<MyError>` because I want to know it's any `AppError` because I might have `<MyError1>`, <MyError2>`, <MyError3>`, etc

Comment: I might have misphrased something - I thought things inside `<>` meant generic

Comment: This is one of the problems I have yet to figure out in Swift. `AppError<Any>` is practically the same as the `MyError` in the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55733949/how-can-i-have-different-enums-on-an-extended-error-class-in-swift) you asked earlier. I haven't figured it out how to cast the generic part of a generic myself for a class like `AppError<MyError>` but something interesting to note is that it does work when casting `Array<T>`. This makes me think that there is a way to do it but I haven't found it. It seems like generics won't work for what you are trying to do.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more about what you are going to do in this function. Maybe we can work it out.

Comment: I elaborated more above. I want to know that an error is from `AppError` to know it has certain properties, without having to explicitly list every single type in the `handle` method.

Comment: @rpecka generics in general are not covariant on the parameterized type, but Array and Optional get special compiler-level treatment so they can do things you can’t.

Answer (score 0):

I saw from another of your posts that you need your error to be more flexible than plain enums so I’ve updated this to do that, still using protocols:

I think you could achieve this with protocols instead:

```swift
protocol AppErrorProtocol: Error {
    func handle()
}

struct AppError<ErrorType>: AppErrorProtocol {
    let error: ErrorType
    init(error: ErrorType) {
        self.error = error
    }
    func handle() {
        print(error)
    }
}

enum MyErrors {
    case one
}

func handleError(_ error: Error) {
    print(type(of: error))
    switch error {
        case let error as AppErrorProtocol:
          error.handle()
        default:
          print("Some other error \(error)")
    }
}

handleError(AppError(error: MyErrors.one))
handleError(AppError(error: "foo"))
```

Comment: This solution would mean I need a case for every error type that extends `AppError`. Had tried this as well :)

Comment: I'm not completely clear on what your goal is, but what if you restrict `ErrorType` to another protocol that has a handler requirement. Maybe something like this gist https://gist.github.com/rudedogdhc/3cef8a2423e7b2a29ee4be37d38c8724

Comment: Hmm let me show what answer I'm going with now, which works. But I still may choose yours as official answer (I've done it before) cause of what the question is asking vs what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 0):

I have designed my own Error handling logic in API side similar to what you are looking. Hope it helps.

**APIError**

```
public enum APIError: Error {

    public enum ResponseFailureReason {

        case castingFailure(description: String)
        case badResponse(statusCode: Int?, error: Error?)
        case jsonDecodingFailure(error: DecodingError?)
        case emptyResponse(description: String)
        case authenticationFailed
        case unknownFailure(error: Error)
        case networkReachabilityFailure
    }

    case invalidURL(url: String)
    case responseFailed(reason: ResponseFailureReason)
    case noInternetConnection(reason: ResponseFailureReason)
}
```

**APIError helper methods**

```
extension APIError {

    public var isInvalidURLError: Bool {
        if case .invalidURL = self {
            return true
        }

        return false
    }

    public var isResponseFailureReason: Bool {
        if case .responseFailed = self {
            return true
        }

        return false
    }

    public var isNetworkReachabilityError: Bool {
        if case .noInternetConnection = self {
            return true
        }

        return false
    }

    public var isAuthenticationFailed: Bool {
        if self.isResponseFailureReason,
            case let .responseFailed(reason) = self,
            case .authenticationFailed = reason {

            return true
        }

        return false
    }
}
```

**This is how errors are thrown.**

```
let failureReason: APIError.ResponseFailureReason = .jsonDecodingFailure(error: decodingError)
throw APIError.responseFailed(reason: failureReason)

throw APIError.responseFailed(reason: .badResponse(statusCode: statusCode, error: error))

throw APIError.responseFailed(reason: .authenticationFailed)
```

**This is how errors are identified and handled**

```
func handleAuthFailure(_ err: APIError?) -> Bool {
    if let error = err {
        if error.isAuthenticationFailed {
            print("Received Authentication failure")
            return true
        }
    }

    return false
}

func handleNetworkReachabilityFailure(_ err: APIError?) -> Bool {
    if let error = err {
        if error.isNetworkReachabilityError,
            case let .noInternetConnection(reason) = error,
            case .networkReachabilityFailure = reason {

            return true
        }
    }

    return false
}

func handleBadResponse(for error: Error) {

    if let error = error as? APIError,
        error.isResponseFailureReason,
        case let .responseFailed(reason) = error,
        case let .badResponse(statusCode, _) = reason {

        if statusCode == HTTPStatusCode.forbidden.rawValue {
            // handle Forbidden case
            return
        } else if statusCode == HTTPStatusCode.conflict.rawValue {
            // handle conflict case
            return
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this mean ALL error types get listed into this enum at the top?

Comment: Yes. while parsing response, i somehow fit the failures in any one of the enums, like Bad response is http error code other than 200 to 300 and 401 is authentication failed and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Swift docs make it clear that one should try to use an `enum`. That makes the solutions for my goal overly complicated. I ended up making a base class and then extending it for my various error types.

I first setup my base error class.

```
typealias AppErrorContext = [String:Any]?;

class AppError: Error {
    public let message: String;
    public let context: AppErrorContext;
    public let line: Int;
    public let function: String;
    public let file: String;

    init(
        message: String,
        context: AppErrorContext = [:],
        line: Int = #line,
        file: String = #file,
        function: String = #function
        ) {
        self.message = message;
        self.context = context;
        self.line = line;
        self.function = function;
        self.file = file;
    }
}
```

I then created several classes like:

```
// class names here are for demo purpose only
class EntityMissingInfoError: AppError {}
class EntityNotFoundError: AppError {}
class ConnectionUnableToCompleteError: AppError {}
class ConnectionNoResponseError: AppError {}
```

If I can then throw like `throw EntityMissingInfoError(message: "Something was missing!", context: ["expected": "id", "received": "notid")`

My calling lines are then like

```
do {
  try methodThatThrows();
}
catch is EntityMissingInfoError {
  // do nothing / ignore
}
catch let error {
  ErrorHandler.handle(error: error);
}
```

My `ErrorHandler` is then simply this:

```
struct ErrorHandler {
    static func handle(error: Error) {
        var message: String;
        var line: Int = 0;
        var file: String = "[Unknown]";
        var function: String = "[Unknown]";
        var context: AppErrorContext = [:];

        if let appError = error as? AppError {
            message = appError.message;
            line = appError.line;
            file = appError.file;
            function = appError.function;
            context = appError.context;

        } else {
            message = error.localizedDescription;
        }

        let logContext: [String:Any] = [
            "type": String(describing: error),
            "line": line,
            "function": function,
            "file": file,
            "context": context ?? [:]
        ]

        // in practice, logging to service rather than printing
        print(message);
        print(logContext);
    }
}
```

The Error handler can now do the special logic for any of my errors, while still having a default case for generic errors thrown from other libraries.